# Numerical integration/Quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I want to find constants a, b, c and d that will produce a quadrature formula:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} af(-1) + bf(1) +cf'(-1)+df'(1)$$
that has degree of precision 3.

I'm not sure how to go about this. Is Gaussian quadrature possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: It is solvable by setting up a system of four equations in four unknowns.

We are given:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} af(-1) + bf(1) +cf'(-1)+df'(1)$$

I will do the first and you can do the rest:

$$f(x) = x^0 = 1 \implies  \displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 ~ 1~ dx = 2 = a(1) + b(1) + c(0) + d(0) $$

Now repeat this for $f(x) = x^1, x^2, x^3$ and set up and solve the $4x4$ system.

You should arrive at:

$$a = 1, b = 1, c = \dfrac 13, d = -\dfrac 13$$